# How to fetch data from two tables using mysql query with some conditions applied to the second table?

Tags: mysql

I want to generate a result from a MySql query with below requirement.

Table 1 :

```
---------------
| nid | type  |
---------------
|  1  | forum |
|  2  | forum |
|  3  | forum |
|  4  | forum |
---------------
```

Table 2

```
-----------------------
| nid | cid | created |
-----------------------
| 1   | 32  | 123456  |
| 2   | 65  | 123457  |
| 4   | 67  | 123458  |
| 1   | 61  | 123491  |
| 1   | 78  | 123497  |
| 2   | 23  | 123498  |
| 1   | 12  | 123698  |
| 4   | 54  | 132365  |
| 4   | 81  | 135698  |
| 1   | 30  | 168965  |
-----------------------
```

Now i require result like below. (Condition : I need the nid from first table, smallest cid for the corresponding nid in second table WHERE type = 'forum')

```
--------------
| nid | cid  |
--------------
| 1   |  12  |
| 2   |  23  |
| 4   |  67  |
--------------
```

Comment: Do you want all `nid` from first table or only matched `nid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT tbl1.nid,
       min(tbl2.cid) as cid
FROM table1 tbl1
INNER JOIN table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.nid=tbl2.nid
GROUP BY tbl2.nid;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afc3f/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.nid,
       min(t2.cid) as cid
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.nid=t2.nid
GROUP BY t2.nid;
```

Comment: Have you check my posted answer?

Answer (score 0):

This could also work

```
select nid, min(cid) cid 
from table2 
group by nid
```

Answer (score 0):

The above queries are have issues in group by clause. Kindly check this query.

```
  SELECT t1.NID, MIN(t2.CID) AS cis from 
  TAB1 t1 inner join TAB2 t2 on t1.nid = t2.nid
  group by t1.nid
```